# MVC framework - где правильно подключать базу данных?

Tags: symfony, php, yii, zend-framework, mvc

Речь идет не о конкретном фреймворке, а в целом.

База данных в основном используется в моделе, поэтому я подключаю ее в конструкторе родительской моделе, а потом использую в наследниках.

Так правильно или нет?
И если не правильно то почему?

---

**обновил**

Немного непонятно я написал, прошу прощения

В общем я вызываю  статический класс $db=$db::ini(); в конструкторе родительской модели, в моделях же использую $db->sql('запрос');

Настройки подключения прописаны в конфиге.

Т.е. когда я вызываю $db::ini() то происходит коннект к базе с помощью pdo и указатель сохраняется в переменную $db доступную в наследуюмых классах модели

Я смотрел yii, потом какой то чувак на форуме типа сказал все в контроллере нужно делать, а само подключение в бутстрапе, там где автолоад происходит и файлы подключаются.

Я считаю что я делаю правильно, подключаюсь к базе когда это нужно, ведь для этого и есть модель - я прав?

Comment: "подключаю" это как? Устанавливаешь соединение? Если вопрос не о фреймворках, нужно убрать их из тегов. В целом, ты сам ответил на свой вопрос - посмотри как "подключается база данных" во фрейморках и используй способ, который тебе больше подходит.

Comment: Подключается бд в конфиге для разных env разный connection.

Answer (score 3):

Настройки для подключения нужно держать в конфиге, который не в коем случае не должен попадать в репозиторий.

В современных фреймворках (указанных вами в тегах) подключение происходит в момент когда нужно что то взять/изменить/удалить из БД. Тут не нужно ничего придумывать, все придумали за вас.

Например, мы хотим на странице показать форму авторизации (больше ничего кроме формы). Страница грузится, а подключается к БД не происходит из-за ненадобности. А когда юзер отправляет форму с данными авторизации происходит подключение  к БД, дабы найти юзера, который пытается авторизоваться.